# Drawing a texture with an alpha channel doesn't work -- draws black

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I am modifying GLPaint to use a different background, so in this case it is white. Anyway the existing stamp they are using assumes the background is black, so I made a new background with an alpha channel. When I draw on the canvas it is still black, what gives? When I actually draw, I just bind the texture and it works. Something is wrong in this initialization.

Here is the photo [image]

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
{
    CGImageRef brushImage;
    CGContextRef brushContext;
    GLubyte *brushData;
    size_t width, height;

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) 
    {
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
        // In this application, we want to retain the EAGLDrawable contents after a call to presentRenderbuffer.
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        // Create a texture from an image
        // First create a UIImage object from the data in a image file, and then extract the Core Graphics image
        brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"].CGImage;

        // Get the width and height of the image
        width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage);
        height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage);

        // Texture dimensions must be a power of 2. If you write an application that allows users to supply an image,
        // you'll want to add code that checks the dimensions and takes appropriate action if they are not a power of 2.

        // Make sure the image exists
        if(brushImage) 
        {
            brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
            brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, width, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
            CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);
            CGContextRelease(brushContext);
            glGenTextures(1, &brushTexture);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);
            free(brushData);
        }

        //Set up OpenGL states
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        CGRect frame = self.bounds;
        glOrthof(0, frame.size.width, 0, frame.size.height, -1, 1);
        glViewport(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glDisable(GL_DITHER);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
        glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);
        glPointSize(width / kBrushScale);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line here:
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);

Needs to be:
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

One minus the destination alpha can be 0, since the dst alpha is usually 1.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, but I accidentally left that in. ANyway the problem was with premultiplied alphas vs. nonpremultiplied. PNG spec says they are not premultiplied, but GIMP saves them as premult. So you need to use glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);